Issue in Authentication using Passport JS
What is the issue? I am signing in and User using Passport JS is stored in mongoDB, but after logging in authentication is failed !! I am using 2 different users (teacher and parent). Is there any issue in signing in or is there any issue in logging in or any other issue?
All my code parts are here. Please help!!
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const parentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    type: { type: String, default: 'Parent' }
});

parentSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);


const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const teacherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    type: { type: String, default: 'Teacher' }
});

teacherSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Teacher', teacherSchema);


const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require("express-session");
const cors = require('cors');
const connectflash = require('connect-flash');
const expressflash = require("express-flash");
const path = require('path');
const passport = require("passport");
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const teacherRoute = require('./routes/teacherRoute');
const parentRoute = require("./routes/parentRoute");
const loginRoute = require("./routes/loginRoute");
const currUserRoute = require("./routes/currUserRoute");
const Teacher = require("./models/teacherModel");
const Parent = require("./models/parentSchema");

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());

// Database connection
const dbConnect = require('./config/dbConnect');
dbConnect().then(() => {
    console.log("Connection successful");
}).catch(err => console.log(err));

//express-session
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Mentorly',
        ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 14 days
    }),
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 14 days in milliseconds
    }
}));

//Flash
app.use(connectflash());
app.use(expressflash());

//For Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, { id: user.id, type: user.type });
});
passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
    if (obj.type === 'Teacher') {
        Teacher.findById(obj.id, (err, user) => {
            done(err, user);
        });
    } else {
        Parent.findById(obj.id, (err, user) => {
            done(err, user);
        });
    }
});


// Teacher Strategy
passport.use('teacher-local', Teacher.createStrategy());
// Parent Strategy
passport.use('parent-local', Parent.createStrategy());

// Routes
app.use('/api', currUserRoute);
app.use('/api/teacher', teacherRoute);
app.use('/api/parent', parentRoute);
app.use('/login', loginRoute);

app.get('/protected', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: 'This is a protected route', user: req.user });
});

// Middleware to check authentication
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    res.status(401).json({ error: 'User not authenticated' });
}


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});


exports.signupParent = async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const {username, email, password} = req.body;
        const alreadyExists = await Parent.findOne({ email }) || await Parent.findOne({ username });

        if (alreadyExists) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: "Account already exists"
            });
        }

        const newParent = new Parent({ username: username, email: email });
        Parent.register(newParent, password, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
            }
            passport.authenticate('parent-local')(req, res, () => {
                res.status(200).json(user);
            });
        });

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: "Internal Server Error",
            success: false,
            error: err.message
        });
    }
};

exports.signupTeacher = async (req, res) =>{ 
    try {
        const {username, email, password} = req.body;
        const alreadyExists = await Teacher.findOne({ email }) || await Teacher.findOne({ username });

        if (alreadyExists) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: "Account already exists"
            });
        }

        const newTeacher = new Teacher({ username: username, email: email });
        Teacher.register(newTeacher, password, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
            }
            passport.authenticate('teacher-local')(req, res, () => {
                res.status(200).json(user);
            });
        });
        // return res.status(201).json({newTeacher});

    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: "Internal Server Error",
            success: false,
            error: err.message
        });
    }
}

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');

// Login route for Teachers
router.post('/teacher', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('teacher-local', (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!user) return res.status(400).send(info);
        req.logIn(user, (err) => {
            if (err) return next(err);
            return res.status(200).send(user);
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});

// Login route for Parents
router.post('/parent', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('parent-local', (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!user) return res.status(400).send(info);
        req.logIn(user, (err) => {
            if (err) return next(err);
            return res.status(200).send(user);
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});

module.exports = router;

Error while accessing currentUser
After logging in I am getting correct data
I was expecting a successful signup and login but was facing issue for that. I am sending current user and type of user in frontend in React JS.

Can you provide where exactly you are facing errors? Are the errors occurring while trying to signup, login, or access secure routes? Can you also provide details of the errors?
